# the g:link not working while using inside the g:formremote

Tags: java, grails

this is the code for ajax request to the controller i already tried.

```
<g:formRemote onComplete="onComplete()" update="addBlock" autocomplete="off" url="[controller: 'someContoller', action:'someAction']">
```

this is the link inside the form remote and it is not working.

```
<g:link url="[controller:'anotherController',action:'anotherAction']"><button>Go</button></g:link></g:formremote>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are putting url attribute in g:link that's why it is not working. Use this it will help you .

```
<g:link controller:"anotherController",action:"anotherAction">Go</g:link>
```

Comment: you can accept the answer if it works for you so it can help others. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`formRemote` as well as `linkRemote` are deprecated in Grails 3.1. You should use proper Ajax-functions from your favorite JS library instead.